# Type that allows only one of listed value in typeScript

Tags: typescript

Is there type in typeScript that allows only one of listed value ?

What I want:

```js
typethatiwant Animals = ['cat', 'dog'];

let myAnimal: Animals = 'cat'; // good
myAnimal = 'dog'; // good
myAnimal = 'hamster'; // error because 'hamster' not 'cat' or 'dog'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An union type combined with string literals

```
type Animals = 'cat' | 'dog'
```

See it in [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Animals%20%3D%20'cat'%20%7C%20'dog'%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20animal1%3A%20Animals%20%3D%20'cat'%0D%0Alet%20animal2%3A%20Animals%20%3D%20'hamster')

Comment: It could be noted that this depend on a concept called [string literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).